# How to display data on initState in Flutter?

Tags: java, flutter, bluetooth

I'm a newbie, can anyone answer my questions.
I'm getting data from Bluetooth through cross-platform from Java to Flutter.
The problem I have is when I click some button only I'm getting data and displayed in the flutter UI, but I have to display the data in init state.
What is happening or what I should do to get the data while the page loads.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
 
  static const recvMsg = const MethodChannel('simpleReceiveChannel');


  String fromBle = "waiting for message";
  String _receivedMsg = "waiting to receive....";
  Future<void> receivingMsg() async {
    try {
      var result = await recvMsg.invokeMethod('receiveMsgFunction');
      _receivedMsg = result;
      print("Result of Receiving: $result");
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("error + '${e.message}' ");
    }
    setState(() {
      fromBle = _receivedMsg;
    });
  }
  


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    receivingMsg();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Refresh'),
          onPressed: () {
            receivingMsg();
          },
        ),
        Text(fromBle),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
//import 'dart:convert';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  static const recvMsg = const MethodChannel('simpleReceiveChannel');
  String fromBle = "waiting for message from Bluetooth";
  //String _receivedMsg = "waiting to receive....";
  bool isData = false;
  Future<void> receivingMsg() async {
    try {
      var result = await recvMsg.invokeMethod('receiveMsgFunction');
      if (result == null) {
        isData = false;
      } else {
        isData = true;
      }
      // _receivedMsg = result;
      fromBle = result;

      print("Result of Receiving: $result");
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("error + '${e.message}' ");
    }
    setState(() {
      isData = true;
      // fromBle = _receivedMsg;
    });
  }
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    receivingMsg();
  }

  Widget noDataScreen() {
    return Text("Data yet to receive");
  }

  Widget dataScreen() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: receivingMsg(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        return Center(
            child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Refresh'),
              onPressed: () {
                receivingMsg();
              },
            ),
            Text(fromBle),
          ],
        ));
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isData ? dataScreen() : noDataScreen();
  }
}
```

Comment: There seems to be some issue with your `receiveMsgFunction`. Just replace your `invokeMethod` line with this `var result = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => 'FooMessage');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your Center widget in build method with future builder and in future call the method instead of clicking on the button.

Like so

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: receivingMsg(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
    return Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Refresh'),
              onPressed: () {
                receivingMsg();
              },
            ),
            Text(fromBle),
          ],
        ));
  },);
```

Comment: Thank you it helped me..Actually, I want to show one widget when data arrives and other when there is no data. But my code works but not as intended. First time data coming (isData) is false so I have show noDataScreen widget and when data comes from it shows dataScreen....here is my code.

Comment: You can also achieve that with future builder you can a check
`if(snapshot.hasData)
return Widget();
else
return AnotherWidget();`

you can check the futureBuilder class in this documentation. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: I tried it .I'm sending data from docklight(serial communication protocols) .When the page loads there is no data so it shows correct widget but when I send data through docklight ,I'm getting data from JAva toast message ,but the widget doesn't render.Can you please tell me why and whats happening.

Comment: After you get the data you should use setState in order to make the widget render again or consider using streams and stream builder so when the data change the widget wrapped with stream builder rebuild itself.